# private member of "this" disappears after creating a new object

Tags: c++, debugging

I am writing a program, that uses a vector of a class of objects. And new objects are (required to)pushed into the vector in a method of this class. However, some of the private members of "this" disappears after pushing back a new object.

Here is a simplified version of the code that demonstrates this bug.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class foo{
public:
    foo(std::string n);
    std::string getName();
    void bar(std::vector<foo> &a);
private:
    std::string name;
};

foo::foo(std::string n){
    name = n;
}

std::string foo::getName(){
    return name;
}

void foo::bar(std::vector<foo> &a){
    std::cout<<"";//breakpoint 1
    a.push_back(foo("I am two"));
    std::cout<<"";//breakpoint 2
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<foo> a;
    a.push_back(foo("I am one"));
    a[0].bar(a);
    std::cout<<a[0].getName()<<a[1].getName()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The "name" of "this" is "I am one" at breakpoint 1, but it turns out to be "" at breakpoint 2. Although this does not seem to alter the output of this program, but it did mess up my original program. How can I make "this" untouched under this circumstance? And I would also like to know why this happens.

**Some more observation**

This bug only happens when I use a member of that vector to call `bar()`(in this case `a[0]`). Creating another object and call this function generates no bug.

Comment: Perhaps use const reference when passing parameters is a good idea i.e. `foo::foo (const std::string &str)`

Comment: If `push_back` has to resize the vector, I suppose it might invalidate `this` halfway through `bar()`.

Comment: @EdHeal In my other program I have things to pass which is not constant, and was modified in this process.

Comment: It says that the constructor is not going to modify the parameter and a reference will do - instead of doing a copy

Comment: @EdHeal sorry I didn't really get your point. `bar` needs to modify  vector `a` so I have to pass it by reference; and also the one being destroyed is `this` not `a`...

Comment: Thre `foo` constructor is what i pointed out

Comment: You can make `getname` const as well.

Comment: The `foo` class's members and constructors are not really important here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. `this` is pointing to an object contained within the vector. When a vector is mutated, it may reallocate its buffer and change the location of its contained objects. Therefore, as soon as you call any mutating member, `this` may be invalidated. Attempting to access any member of `this` after that is undefined behaviour.

This architecture is fundamentally incorrect and cannot be trivially fixed. The simplest thing to do is to swap out the vector for a list, which cannot reallocate its members. However, generally speaking, this is a pretty nasty architecture - the `foo` class should not have the ability to affect its own container in this way and this is just one of the many reasons why. A proper solution would be to move out of `foo` any ability to affect its container or owner.

Comment: `deque` would be a less dramatic swap than `list` would

Comment: It doesn't really fix the problem, which is that `foo` knows far too much about its container/owner. Also, for some mutations `deque` can still move the objects around and not completely preserve the invariant.

Comment: One solution is to make bar static, which means it wont have access to `this`, but it does not need access to `this` because it only modifies the passed in vector and adds a new `foo` to that vector.

Comment: Making it a non-member is far preferable, as it has no member requirements.

Answer (score 0):

> This bug only happens when I use a member of that vector to call
>   bar()(in this case a[0]). Creating another object and call this
>   function generates no bug.

This is not a bug, @Puppy has correctly explained the reason for what you are observing.

You have created an object of `foo` and added it to a vector.
When you call `bar()`, the `this` pointer is setup to point to the address of `foo` inside the vector. 
i.e. `this = &a[0];`

So far so good, but as soon as you add another item to the vector that holds foo, the vector reallocates its internal buffer and moves your original foo to another location in memory. This operation does not effect the value of `this` pointer inside `bar()` that was already setup before `bar()` was called.
So now the `this` pointer is pointing to the old location of foo which is no longer a valid address for foo.

IOW, calling `bar()` is equivalent to doing:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<foo> a;
    a.push_back(foo("I am one"));
    //breakpoint 1
    foo* thisfoo = &a[0];
    a.push_back(foo("I am two"));
    //breakpoint 2 -- oops thisfoo is no longer valid
    std::cout<<a[0].getName()<<a[1].getName()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What you need to realise is that the value of `this` pointer is not dynamic inside the member function and if you move or delete the object `this` points to within a member, `this` will not automatically follow your object around in memory. It is the same reason you can `delete this` and `this` will still continue pointing to the same location, though now that location will no longer be valid. Which is why you should `this = null` after a delete.

A solution: Make `bar()` static, it does not require access to the `this` pointer.

Comment: What does this add over the existing answer?